# UINavigationController TitleView not displayed from ViewController NavigationItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

Whenever I add a viewController to a navigationController while in landscape the title view  appears on certain views but not on others.  ie: I have a navigation controller, add 3 view controllers, first two show titleview appropriately, third one doesn't show one at all.  But the navigation controller grabs the titleview from the ViewController like it's supposed to, I wrote the value of it to the console and it is correct, but it just doesn't show on the screen for whatever reason.  Any ideas?

Oh yeah works perfectly while in portrait orientation.

Here's another fun part, if I push the trouble view controller into the navigationController in landscape the titleView isn't there, then without any user interaction, I rotate the device back to portrait and the titleView appears, then I rotate the device back to landscape and it stays!

It's like the drawing of my TitleView was blocked even though I used InvokeOnMainThread.  Nothing is running in the main thread (or anywhere for that matter) during that call.

Here's my structure:

```
Window
  TabBarController 
    NavigationController 
      ViewController
    NavigationController
      ViewController
```

Here's my order of operations:

1. Create View Controller
2. Add Title view to view controller
3. Push View Controller onto NavigationController (InvokeOnMainThread)

Comment: why do u use two nav controller use only one Window TabBarController NavigationController ViewController enough then create other viewcontroller then push to it

Comment: Each navigation controller represents a different interface that is shown for each different tab.  Only using one navigation controller per tab.

Comment: here u have create two nav controller for 3tabs.so create like that to last one

Comment: Sorry I was just showing the basic structure, really I have 4 tabs and each one of them can go anywhere from 2 viewcontrollers deep to 5 or 6 depending on how detailed they are getting in the scope. However each tab in the tabbarController only has 1 navigationController. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Adding the titleview onto the viewController in InvokeOnMainThread made it appear.  I don't know why this changed the outcome.  I figured I would just have to push the viewController onto the NavigationController inside of the InvokeOnMainThread.  If anyone would care to explain why that is I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Any type of UI manipulation needs to be done on the main thread. Otherwise the results are unpredictable, as is in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the controller title after the controller is pushed? This kind of behavior happens to me and the way to make sure the title appears is to mandatory set the navBar title in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method as follows:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"The title";
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The Title";
```

Other thing that happened to me is to set the leftBarButton or RightBarButton of a navigation bar without success in the viewDidLoad method, but they appear correctly when setting the bar buttons in the viewWillAppear method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed timing seems to be REALLY important. I was setting the `titleView` in the navigation view delegate's `willShowViewController` and while left and right items were ok, `titleView` would flicker and disappear. Now I set it directly in overridden `pushViewController` method.

Comment: Setting the self.navigationItem.title on the viewWillAppear method did the trick for me. On viewDidLoad it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem maybe that when your function is called, the navigation item is nil. So when you call self.navigationITem.title, it do nothing. Later, when the view is rotated, the navigationItem is not nil anymore so changing the title works.

If you do the code in ViewDidLoad function beware that ViewDidLoad is called the first time someone calls viewController.view and not the first time the view is displayed. So the view may not be in a navigationController yet.

For example, this can happend if you do :

```
viewController.view.backgroundColor = ... ; 
[navigationController pushViewController:viewController]
```

The first line will call ViewDidLoad even if the controller is not in a navigationController yet.